# XSL FO: Print Just A Single Blank Line Between Paragraphs

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have some XML data and an XSL FO stylesheet to format the XML.  I have the following XML document:

```
<Content>
<Para>Paragraph One.</Para> 
<Para /> 
<Para>Paragraph Two.</Para> 
<Para /> 
<Para>Paragraph Three.</Para>
</Content>
```

The desired output after styling with an FO stylesheet would be:

```
Paragraph One.

Paragraph Two.

Paragraph Three.
```

The actual output I am getting is below, there are always two blank lines.

```
Paragraph One.


Paragraph Two.


Paragraph Three.
```

The stylesheet code I am using is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<xsl:variable name="NewLine">
    <xsl:text>&#10;&#10;</text>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="pageSetup">
                <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pageSetup">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>

    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Para">
    <fo:block
        linefeed-treatment="preserve"
        white-space-collapse="false">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="text() != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$NewLine" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What's the point of inserting line feeds? To add extra blank space after a paragraph? If so, you should add a padding or a margin to your `<fo:block>`s.

Answer (score 0):

The conventional way to get space between blocks would be to use the `space-before` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#space-before) and/or `space-after` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#space-after) properties.

If you are going to persist with empty `Para` elements in your XML, you can ignore them and use `space-after` by replacing your template for `Para` with:

```
<xsl:template match="Para[text()]">
    <fo:block space-after="1em">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```